# How to call back button inside movieclip from main stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I create one button which will go to one movieclip. There are 2 buttons inside the movieclip. I want to make one of the buttons to return back to the main stage and resume my timer.

Here is my code for the button in the main stage :

```
buttonpopup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_137);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_137(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    popup2.gotoAndStop(2); // where the popup buttons exist 
    countdownTimer1.stop(); 
}
```

And here is the code for the button inside the movieclip :

```
popupno.popup2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func);  
function func(event:MouseEvent):void  
 { gotoAndPlay(2); //back to keyframe 2 in main stage        
  countdownTimer1.start();  
 }
```

Comment: Where did you defined the function that will resume the timer ? Inside that MovieClip or on the main timeline ... ? You have just to call that function ...

Comment: I defined the function that will resume the timer inside the movieclip.. but I got this error .. 1119: Access of possibly undefined property popup2 through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.

Comment: Could you show the code of that function and how did you tried to call it to get that error ?

Comment: Here is the code to go to the  popup button buttonpopup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_137);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_137(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   popup2.gotoAndStop(2); // where the popup buttons exist
      countdownTimer1.stop();  
}

Comment: And here is the coding for the button inside the movieclip  

 popupno.popup2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func);

function func(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 gotoAndPlay(2); //back to keyframe 2 in main stage
 countdownTimer1.start();
 
}

Comment: Could you please add these codes to your question and explain more the situation because I think that's not clear enough to help you resolve this problem ?

Comment: So if I understand you, your MovieClip is called `popupno` and the button that should resume the timer is `popup2`. Is that correct ? Then, where you have put the second code : `popupno.popup2.addEventListener ... `, inside that MovieClip (I don't think but just to be sure) or in the main timeline ?

Comment: No. The button that should resume the timer is popupno.. not popup2. and the code i put it inside the movieclip